# Function to encrypt a string using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, encryption

I need to write a function that gets a string and a number `N`, the function will return in the same pointer the encrypted string. The function will encrypt a string by the following rules:

1. Reverse the string, e.g: if the string is `"Amnon"` the result would be `"nonmA"`.
2. After the reverse, each letter needs to be replaced by the value of `N`, e.g: if `N`=3 then instead of `"nonmA"` the result would be `"qrqpD"`.

I had no problem doing the reverse part but I'm struggling with switching each letter. Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void StRreverse(char* mystr, int N);

void StRreverse(char* mystr, int N)
{
    int c, length, n;
    char *begin, *end, temp;
    length = strlen(mystr);
    begin = mystr;
    end = mystr;
    for (c = 0; c < length - 1; c++)
    {
        end++;
    }
    for (c = 0; c < length / 2; c++)
    {
        temp = *end;
        *end = *begin;
        *begin = temp;
        begin++;
        end--;
    }
}
void main()
{
    char string[100];

    printf("Enter some text\n");
    gets(string);

    StRreverse(string);
    printf("Reverse of entered string is \"%s\".\n", string);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)` and never use `gets` as it is dangerous because it doesn't prevent buffer . Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: You need to pass two arguments to `StReverse()`, but you give it just one argument.

Comment: where's the 2nd part ?

Comment: Where is the encryption?

Comment: What would the encrypted string be if the string to be encrypted is `"XYZ"` and `N=3`?

Comment: @CoolGuy I only passed 1 argument because at first I didnt add int N and just wanted to check if the reverse works and it did, now I added N but I dont know how to continue from there. about it being XYZ and N=3 it will be ABC

Comment: @AmnonHanuhov , shouldn't it be `CBA` ( after reversing ) ?

Answer (score 2):

First, identify 'letters' in a portable way:

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

Then you can use `isalpha(mystr[c])` to generally identify letters, and specifically `islower` and `isupper`. Then, on each letter, add your constant *modulo 26*. That is, if `a` becomes `b`, then `y` becomes `z` and `z` would be `a` again.

This operation is encoding-dependent as not all encodings have "a" to "z" and "A" to "Z" defined consecutively. Fortunately, it's unlikely you have such a system :) (although it is an interesting exercise to work out a way where this would *not* be an issue!).

The trick is to 'wrap around' with an offset of either `A` or `a`, so capitals and lowercase need a separate line of code:

```
if (isupper(mystr[c]))
   mystr[c] = 'A' + ((mystr[c]-'A' + N + 26) % 26);
if (islower(mystr[c]))
   mystr[c] = 'a' + ((mystr[c]-'a' + N + 26) % 26);
```

where `N` can be as low as `-25`, or as high as you want. That lower limit (and the addition of `26` in the statements) is because in some implementations of C, taking the modulus of a negative number returns a negative number as well.

To decode this text -- properly called the Caesar Cypher --, you can apply the same formula with `-N`.

Comment: I have not yet studied isupper and islower so I assume I am not allowed to do that, is there any other method?

Comment: I think without using these functions the code should look like this: for (c = 0; c<length; c++)   
 {
  if ((mystr[c] >= 'A') && (mystr[c] <= 'Z'))
  {
   mystr[c] = 'A' + ((mystr[c] - 'A' + N + 26) % 26);
  }
  if ((mystr[c] >= 'a') && (mystr[c] <= 'z'))
  {
   mystr[c] = 'a' + ((mystr[c] - 'a' + N + 26) % 26);
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do switching is by adding the number to that character. For example

`char str[n] = {'a','b','c','d'};

for(int i=0; i less than n; i++)
     str[i] = str[i] +3; // we are adding 3 to switch
`

I dont remeber the ascii number for small 'a'. But if its 36 the above code will make it 39 which will be 'd'. Hope it works for u